# Htaccess: redirect with unique id and title

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all pages like:

> example.com/545/name-of-the-page/

to

> example.com/name-of-the-page_545/

where "name-of-the-page" it is different for every page and "545" it is the id, also different.

I just don't know how can i do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2_$1/ [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RewriteRules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)$ /$2_$1/ [QSA]
```